# ItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview

I have problem with onItemClickListener, its not working for my code 
My code is

```
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);              
            CustomAadpter adapter = new CustomAadpter(this,R.layout.file_view_layout,R.id.contact_name,names);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    System.out.println("view clicked is"+arg1);

                }

            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? System.out not printing?

Comment: Any exception or error? please give some description.

Comment: @thinksteep yes its not printing anything

Comment: Android Killer its not throwing any exception neither showing any error do i have to set any parameters to list before it?

Comment: Post your layout xml and full code of java class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Position is"+ arg2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Can be used if you want to show the postion as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
Toast.makeText(context,"message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```